# Changing Grid Image source on Button Click via Xaml.cs

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I am fairly new to Windows Store Application Development. I am stuck at trying to change the image of the grid via c# code.

This is my Mainpage.Xaml code

```
 <Grid x:Name="BG" KeyDown="operation" Width="1327" Height="740">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <ImageBrush  Stretch="UniformToFill" ImageSource="Assets/background.jpg"/>
                </Grid.Background>
<Button  x:Name="ThemeButton" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" FontSize="14" Content="Theme 1" Margin="25,0,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Click="ChangeBG"></Button>
```

This is my Mainpage.Xaml.cs Code

```
  private void ChangeBG(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ImageBrush b1 = new ImageBrush();
            b1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"D:\Visual Studio Project File\Sadiqali Calculator\Sadiqali Calculator\Assets\Theme2.png"));
            BG.Background = b1;

        }
```

When the button is pressed I am getting a black background instead of the picture. The above code is from other threads.

How can I change the image source of the grid via code on click of a button?

Comment: The question seems to be about a Windows Store App, and not a desktop (WPF) application? Such an App can't access files in an arbitrary directory, like D:\...

Comment: See [File access and permissions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh967755.aspx).

Comment: Yes, It is about Windows Store Application. How would I go about telling the code to point towards the apps asset folder? What changes would I make to the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank You Everyone! You have helped me solve it!

This is what I changed the code to and it worked.

```
ImageBrush b1 = new ImageBrush();
        b1.ImageSource = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"ms-appx:///Assets/Theme2.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
        BG.Background = b1;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine here when I use my own images.

Check the location of D:\Visual Studio Project File\Sadiqali Calculator\Sadiqali Calculator\Assets\Theme2.png ... are you sure this is valid?

Also - ChangeBG will run on the UI thread if invoked from the button click.

Comment: Yes the path is valid. The Image is also available in my assets folder in solution explorer. I have tried changing the path to Assets/theme2.png but it has given me converting errors.

Comment: "Also - ChangeBG will run on the UI thread if invoked from the button click." elaborate please?

Comment: You had said "The above code is from other threads.", suggesting other than the UI thread.  But a button click event will *only* fire from the UI thread.

Comment: @JamesHarcourt It is a windows store application. Sorry for not clarifying